# Reliable way to automatically update Click-Once network deployed application

Tags: vb.net, deployment, clickonce, auto-update, intranet

I have been working on this for months now with no real success.
I’ve cobbled together code from various sources and this is what I have.

Sometime it works as expected and sometimes the app just freezes and sometimes it updates 4 times.

I have a timer interval at 5 minutes that checks if an update is available and if one is Updates and Restarts. Simple Right?

The application is network deployed and sometimes users will leave the app running for weeks not logging off. When an update is published they may get errors because of new functionality or database changes.

Why such varied results?

> Here is the Form Load event...

`Me.Timer2.Interval = 300000 Me.Timer2.Start()`

> Here is the Timer_Tick Event...

```
 Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick

    If CheckForUpdateDue() Then
        My.Forms.PopupLoading.Show()
        My.Forms.PopupLoading.Label1.Text = "Project is Updating Please Wait..."
        My.Forms.PopupLoading.Refresh()
        Dim ad As ApplicationDeployment = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment
        ad.Update()
        My.Settings.Save()
        My.Forms.PopupLoading.Close()
        My.Forms.Popup_Restarting.Show()
        Application.Restart()
    End If

End Sub
```

> Here is the CheckForUpdateDue Function...

```
 Private Function CheckForUpdateDue() As Boolean
    Dim isUpdateDue As Boolean = False
    If ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed Then
        Dim AD As ApplicationDeployment = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment
        If AD.CheckForUpdate() Then
            isUpdateDue = True
        End If
    End If
    CheckForUpdateDue = isUpdateDue
End Function
```

[Application Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKTRY.jpg)

[Application Update Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWp3a.jpg)

Comment: Could you check for an update, call a batch file that will wait 5 seconds before relaunching the app, shut the app, and let Click-Once do its job?

Comment: Or another table that has the app/database version that forces the app to close if it has the wrong version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with...

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim ct As Date = DateTime.Now
    If ct.Hour = 22 Then
        Dim info As UpdateCheckInfo = Nothing

        If ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed Then
            Dim AD As ApplicationDeployment = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment

            Try
                info = AD.CheckForDetailedUpdate()
            Catch dde As DeploymentDownloadException
                MessageBox.Show("The new version of the application cannot be downloaded at this time. " & ControlChars.Lf & ControlChars.Lf & "Please check your network connection, or try again later. Error: " + dde.Message)
                Return
            Catch ioe As InvalidOperationException
                MessageBox.Show("This application cannot be updated. It is likely not a ClickOnce application. Error: " & ioe.Message)
                Return
            End Try

            If info.UpdateAvailable Then
                Dim doUpdate As Boolean = True

                If doUpdate Then
                    Try
                        'restart application first
                        Application.Restart()
                        'then do update
                        AD.Update()
                        'when the application is restarted again it will be update
                    Catch dde As DeploymentDownloadException
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot install the latest version of the application. " & ControlChars.Lf & ControlChars.Lf & "Please check your network connection, or try again later.")
                        Return
                    End Try
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

taken from [Microsoft VS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-check-for-application-updates-programmatically-using-the-clickonce-deployment-api?view=vs-2017)
seems to be working 
will wait and see.....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [`My.Application.Deployment.CheckForUpdate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.checkforupdate?view=netframework-4.7.2) is the way to go.  It checks the `UpdateLocation` to see if an update is available and asks the user to download it or you can force a silent update with `My.Application.Deployment.CheckForUpdate(true)`.

I tried using this on my project in debug mode, and it threw a `InvalidDeploymentException`, but I think it should work in production code with a Click-Once Deployment

Comment: The requirements are to have this code run not during business hours and run without user involvement. Hence the timer.

Comment: @JDesigns Right... I was trying to point you in the right direction. I had no intention of writing your code for you.